# Spaces in variable names not working with filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter a few rows of a tibble that looks like this:

```
site  crop  variable   value  
nash  corn  nit leach  4
nash  corn  nit gas    5
nash  corn  soil carb  3
nash  corn  phosphorus 7 
nash  corn  clay       2
```

I have tried

```
dplyr::filter(df, variable %in% c("nit leach", "nit gas", "soil carb"))
```

but I get an empty tibble with no errors. What's the problem here? The spaces? Any way around it? I tried backticks with no luck.

Comment: Your example dataset works for me.  Check to make sure there aren't any extra spaces at the end of `variable` values; e.g., "nit leach " instead of "nit leach".

Comment: They put a space before each value. Argh.